# c# jagged array changes itself

Tags: c#, function, jagged-arrays

I've run into a problem. I created a jagged array (input), then I go through some functions and expected to create another jagged array from it (output). But somehow original array was also changed in that process.
How can I avoid changes in the original array?

```
double[][] input;
    double[][] output;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        input = new double[][]
        {
            new double[] {0,1,2,3 },
            new double[] {9,8 },
            new double[] {14,5,0 },
            new double[] {2.0,2.3,2.5 }
        };
        output = function(input);
    }
    static double[][] function (double[][] ins)
    {
        double[][] ous = ins;
        int leng = ins.GetLength(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < leng; i++)
        {
            int lung = ins[i].GetLength(0);
            for (int j = 0; j < lung; j++)
                ous[i][j] += 14.4;
        }
        return ous;
    }
```

Comment: here's the problem `double[][] ous = ins;`

Comment: @AlekseyL. i added this because both arrays are identical in size, so that I didn't have to declare it again. But the problem is tha "input" array changes.

Comment: As Aleksey pointed out, you are basically assigning the reference, not copying the values. So in memory you have just 1 structure and 2 pointers to it. That's why it changes.

Comment: @3615 So this means that "ous=ins" and "ins=ous"? I thought this was like ordinary value assignment. Why does it changes "input" if i don't reference it?

Comment: @Leinad because array is reference type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ous` variable points to the same array as `ins` (reference). You should copy it to new array. For example using linq:

```
static T[][] CopyArray<T>(T[][] source)
{
    return source.Select(s => s.ToArray()).ToArray();
}
```

And use it:

```
double[][] ous = CopyArray(ins);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't quite get it, but it works now.
So in my original code, what I essentially did was assign the same 4 arrays to both jagged arrays, and when i changed them inside second arrray, they were also changed in first one?

Comment: To be more specific, you assigned both variables to same jagged array.